# Limit decimal places in scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I was trying to write a function which takes a double and an integer as input and returns the double value with precision after decimal point.

```
def decimal_value(d: Double, p: Integer) : 
  Double = {
   if (d >= 0) {
     BigDecimal.(d).setScale(p, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
   }
   else
     d
}
```

My input was 1.140060000 and I'm expecting the output as 1.14006, but it was  returning 1.140060000. It is not considering the 0's after the 5 precision points.

Comment: This may be a problem with the way you are displaying the value. Can you tell us where you are seeing this value displayed as "1.140060000"?

Comment: Also, why the `apache-spark` tag? Is this a Spark question?

Answer (score 0):

Doubles do not store a precision; they all just have the exact same precision. And they are also binary, so they might not exactly match the `BigDecimal` they came from. If you need to retain that precision info, I would recommend you just keep it as a `BigDecimal` or even convert it to a `String`.

Comment: Please don't recommend using strings to store numbers.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but from the question and the concern about "1.4006" vs "1.40060000" I thought it might be the case that that what is really wanted is a number properly formatted for immediate display, in which case a String *might* be the correct type. But yes, keep it as a BigDecimal for most of the lifetime of whatever you're doing, and only convert to String at the last possible time. Don't *store* it as a String.

Answer (score 0):

First, when I compiled your code snippet in repl it throws a compilation error.

`BigDecimal.(d)` -> is incorrect syntax. It should be `BigDecimal(d)`

After correcting it when I compiled and ran the code, it gives correct output.

```
 scala> def decimal_value(d: Double, p: Integer) : 
     |   Double = {
     |    if (d >= 0) {
     |      BigDecimal(d).setScale(p, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
     |    }
     |    else
     |      d
     | }
decimal_value: (d: Double, p: Integer)Double

scala> decimal_value(1.140060000, 5)
res4: Double = 1.14006
```

Answer (score 0):

`1.140060000` and `1.14006` are the same number, so it looks like this question is about way the value appears when you print it out. Calling `toString` on this `Double` gives "1.14006" which is what you wanted, so it is not clear why you are getting "1.140060000"

You can use the string formatting operations to make sure you get the specific output that you want:

```
val str = f"$d7.1f"
```